# Markdown on Python script output adding unwanted <p> tags

Tags: python, markdown

I am using ‘markdown’ on the string output of a Python script, but finding unwanted `<p>` tags in my html5. Can this behavior be suppressed? I am also finding newlines are stripped for no reason. Is that normal?

Comment: What is `'markdown'` on a string output of a Python script? See: [mcve]

Comment: I'm using it to reduce the html tags in my script and improve readability. I wonder if this is a recommended use for markdown.

Comment: Please provide a code sample.

Comment: Show the code that outputs this string and how are you making those tags .i.e. your markdown language converter code or something ?

Comment: For example if I say   `print(markdown.markdown("\n\nXXX", output_format='HTML5'))` it deletes the newlines and wraps the XXX in <p> tags. Is this its intended behavior?

Comment: That is exactly what I would expect. What did you expect?

Comment: I expected to have control over where paragraphs fell, and to use newlines to structure my html for readability.

Comment: In Markdown, HTML elements are represented by whitespace (i.e., paragraphs are created by adding blank lines between blocks of text). That doesn't seem to fit your use case, but without some clear examples, we can't be sure. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49123270/edit) your question to add some more details. At least provide a sample input, the actual output and the output you expected.